# Google app invites, how to check status from sender side

Tags: java, android, google-app-invites

Is it possible to check invitation from sender side?
I've requirement to grant sender when invitation is succeed
(user has installed app).
I see api for
AppInvite.AppInviteApi.updateInvitationOnInstall(mGoogleApiClient, invitationId);
But no information how to get the status.

Thanks!

Comment: Could You add some tags? What language, what platform?

Answer (score 0):

I've asked on github and got answer.

@vladimir-belous currently there is no way to check on the status of an individual invitation. I'll mark this as a feature request, thanks!

Origin:
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/28